# coordinate systems produce submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism, submanifold

In his book "Semiriemannian geometry with applications to relativity", Barrett O'Neil says on page 16 under definition 26 that "coordinate systems produce submanifolds.If T:U->R^n is a coordinate system in a manifold M then holding any n-m of the coordinate functions constant produces an m- dimensional submanifold." My question is ,is this submanifold the same as the inverse image of [R^m×{0}] under T? If yes then since this set is open in M it should be a manifold of the same dimension. This is open in M because T is a homeomorphism and [R^m×{0}] is open in R^n. Where am i going wrong and what is an explicit description of this submanifold?
Thanks.

Comment: That set isn't open in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: isn't it diffeomorphic to R^m?

Comment: (Think about the $x$-axis in 2D

Comment: yes you are right...could you please answer the remaining question?

Comment: I can at least ask a simpler question. Consider a singleton set. It is homeomorphic to some singleton set which is a subset of a topological space $X$. Therefore every singleton set is open in every topological space. True or false?

Comment: that is not true

Comment: ok i got it now...what about an explicit description of this submanifold? and why is it m-dimensional?

Comment: Try thinking about the precise statement you are implicitly using when you say the homeomorphic image of an open set is open